# Oneliner to create a map from an array of maps in JS/ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, dictionary

Is it possible to create a map from an array of maps **in one line**. Using pure JS or ExtJS 4.0?

**Sample Input**

```
[{key:"US", value:"United States"}, {key:"JO", value:"Jordan"}, {key:"PA", value: "Palestine"}, {key:"CA", value:"Canada"}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"US":"United States", "JO": "Jordan", "PA":"Palestine", "CA":"Canada"}
```

*Note: I know Ext.Array.map exists but I am not aware if it can return a different type other than array.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JS's native [`reduce` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(obj, val) {
    obj[val.key] = val.value;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Not a one-liner but still compact. You could replace the body of the callback with

```
return obj[val.key] = val.value, obj;
```

but that might be a bit obscure for people who don't know about the comma operator.

As alternative you can just iterate over the array:

```
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to use cross different browsers?

Comment: The link contains a table which lists the browsers that natively support it. It also provides a polyfill. It seems like though that ExtJS does not have such a method.

Comment: I had a look at the ExtJS documentation and it actually lists `reduce` as native array method. I don't know, maybe it is providing the method if it does not exist. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Array